# Exists vs in performance wise

Tags: sql, oracle

What would be performance wise the best practices regarding the use of exists vs in? I've heard that exists means running the main query for each row fetched in the exists statement, which would make it unfeasible if the exists query returns many rows unless both columns are indexed. Does in work the same way or would it execute both queries and compare the outputs?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 t1
WHERE
    t1.col1 = 'A'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            table2 t2
        WHERE
            t2.col3 = 'B'
            AND t2.col2 = t1.col2
    );

---

SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    col1 = 'A'
    AND col2 IN (
        SELECT
            col2
        FROM
            table2
        WHERE
            col3 = 'B'
    );
```

Comment: @Serg sorry, amended.

Comment: In general you'd need to look at a so called *optimizer plan*, which describes which exact select commands are executed by Oracle after running your initial query. I would expect Oracle to easily detect that in both queries the subquery is identical to joining two tables and the filtering the results

Comment: Your example is comparing a "NOT IN" to an "EXISTS", and "NOT IN" has some traps if the column(s) in the select list include a NULL value.

Comment: @GaryMyers sorry, I mistyped.

Comment: `I've heard that exists means running the main query for each row fetched in the exists statement` :: You listen to the wrong people. Besides: IN and EXISTS are different (wrt NULLs), so it makes no sense to compare their performance.

Comment: @wildplasser . . . `IN` and `EXISTS` are pretty much the same.  Perhaps you are confusing them with `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @wildplasser could you please post as an answer an example in which they would be different? I'm struggling to understand the concept.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what would be that difference? Could you please post an example so I can see?

Comment: @wildplasser would exists have the same behaviour with and without index?

Comment: The *behaviour* can be different; the **result** will be the same.